# Javascript - GA and Adwords

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-ads-api

I need some help.

I'm doing campaigns in my Adwords account, which is linked to my Google Analytics Account and has auto-tag enabled.

In adwords I imported a conversion from Google Analytics (goal).
There's been 2 weeks and 0 conversions tracked in Adwords, but theres 9 Goal completions in Analytics... Analytics tells me its (direct)/(not set) traffic goal completions, but its hard to believe...

So, the conversion point is an online payment form. (An iframe placed in my website loading content from other domain, the payment form).

This online payment service allows me to configure marketing tags (google analytics, adwords conversions, facebook pixel, several more..) in which I configured, setting my Google Analytics PropertyID. I assume its working because I see goal completions and I have a funnel created which shows legit data accordingly to the service documentation.

I think the problem might be the Iframe, because the source is a different domain.

I tried following these steps in this [link](https://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2015/06/16/cross-domain-tracking-with-google-tag-manager/) which should allow the cross domain conversion tracking, but I don't see the _ga=1.23434.234234.whatever append to the Iframe source.

Could this happen because I didnt clicked in any ads of my campaign?

I'm also anounncing on Facebook Ads and its working just fine.

---

Another point is this:

PageViews in the iframe always have (direct)/(notset) traffic, I fixed this with Tagmanager and a JS snippet which find the Iframe and appends de UTMS params.

**Any info, or steps to follow would be appreciated.**

**I KNOW THIS IS NOT PROGRAMMING RELATED BUT I THINK YOU CAN HELP ME**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't programming related.  SEO questions should probably go to https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seo

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: This isn't an SEO question, so not sure why you are recommending they go with an SEO tag.

The correct location would be:  https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-adwords

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need any utm params, just AdWords GCLID parameter to hand-over IMO.

1) Do you have your AdWords automated tracking (auto-tagging) set-up?

2) The easiest way how to fix-it is to fire AdWords conversion pixel on the purchase, which would bypass malfunctioning GA tracking

Comment: are you saying in the iframe i should append `&gclid={gclid token}`?

Comment: Yes, that's what I would do